# Prove that "f cross g" is a function from "A cross B" and "C cross D"

Tags: functions, proof-writing

f is a function from A to B and g is a function from C to D. "f cross g" = {(a,b), (c,d) such that (a,b) $\in$ f and (c,d) $\in$ g}

pf. Let (a,c) $\in$ A x C and (b,d) $\in$ B x D. Then a $\in$ A and c $\in$ C. Then b $\in$ B and d $\in$ D.

I feel like I am missing one more step that will help me finish this proof, but I am not seeing it from a definition. I was wondering if I could get some help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $p \in A\times C $ then $p = (a, c), a\in A, c\in C $.

We define $(f \times g)(p)$ as $(f \times g)(p) = (f \times g)(a, c) = (f(a), g(c)) = (b, d) $ but $b \in B$ and $d \in D $ and $(b, d) \in B\times D $.

This shows that $f \times g$ is a function from $A \times C$ to $B \times D $.

$$(f \times g): A \times C \longrightarrow B \times D $$

$$(a, b) \longrightarrow (f(a), g(c)) $$

Comment: Wow just got why products in category theory and type theory are called that/work that way. Great answer.

Comment: @QthePlatypus great I could help. Maths for the win